# Default list for question saving

Tags: feature-request, questions, saves

When it comes to *question saving* on Stack Overflow, they are always "saved *for later*".

Through the user profile's **Saves tab**, it is possible to create lists to organize these bookmarks. However, for each *new question saved*, you still need to select the target list where it should be saved (doing this requires no less than 5 extra clicks)

Additionally, the last chosen list isn't used for the next save; the default destination is always the *For later* list.

I think if the user could select the default list at least, we would have better feature usability here. The solution could certainly be done differently, but I think I shared my point.

Let me know what you think!

Comment: [Also requested in the announcement post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382575/348196).

Comment: Yes, it is an obvious upgrade. We can only hope for some dogfooding use.

Comment: My userscript [SavedPostsHelper.user.js](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/SavedPostsHelper.user.js) adds bulk-moving checkboxes in lists, and adds a quick-move dropdown in the toast immediately after saving a post. I could technically add a default list feature to it too...

Comment: I liked it, @SamuelLiew! Is there a way I can use these features on my SO sites?

Comment: They should work on other SE sites if the UI is exactly the same.